# Intellij IDEA: avoid showing both source and class file in dependency jars

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I found if the jar contains both class and java sources, IDEA will show both of them, and the files names are duplicated in the view, this is kind of annoying, any way to avoid show both source and class files?

[image]

Comment: I wonder, how the heck java sources could show up in a Maven jar...

Comment: Well, this is common in GWT world, as it must have source to compile to js.

Comment: Well, this is a bit strange for a Java world, as they could supply JS sources as resources and .java file are usually stored in `xxx-sources.jar` in Maven repo. There might be a reason for this, but I'm not sure that Idea developers are aware of this...